# Is it possible to write specialization for member function of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T, bool flag>
class A
{
    //...
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }
    //...
};

template<class T>
void A<T, true>::f<T, true>()
{
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
}
```

The code above is wrong and don't compile, but you get the idea of what I'm going to do. So how should I do that?

Comment: Does your compiler allow partial template specialization?

Answer (score 5):

You can't specialize just one method of a class. Usually you can solve that with a template nested class on the same `T`.

```
template <class T, bool flag>
class A
{
    //...
    template <class Q, bool flag>
    class F_Helper
    {
        void operator()()
        {
            std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template <class Q>
    class F_Helper<Q, true>
    {
        void operator()()
        {
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    F_Helper<T> f;
    //...
};
```

Obviously a bit more boilerplate is needed if you do need access to the enclosing class' `this` pointer.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B: But why `template <class Q, bool flag> class F_Helper` instead of `template <bool flag> class F_Helper`?

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what the other answers say, you *can* specialize a member function of a class template. But you need to provide all template arguments

```
template<>
void A<int, true>::f()
{
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
}
```

What you try is not valid:

```
template<typename T>
void A<T, true>::f()
{
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
}
```

Partially specializing a member of a class template for particular arguments of that class template is not valid, so that means "define the member function 'f' of a partial specialization of A for `<T, true>`". Because there is no such partial specialization, the compiler will error out.

If you cannot provide all arguments, you can overload `f` as follows

```
template <class T, bool flag>
class A
{
    template<typename, bool> struct params { };

    void f()
    {
        f(params<T, flags>());
    }

    template<typename U>
    void f(params<U, true>) {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename U, bool flag1>
    void f(params<U, flag1>) {
        std::cout << "dunno" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I stumbled on exactly the same issue, here is an additional example
 http://fabionotes.blogspot.jp/2012/05/template-function-in-template-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specialize whole template class - [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/rGN4C)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, bool flag>
class A
{
    //...
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }
    //...
};

template<class T>
class A<T, true>
{
    //...
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specialize the whole class:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, bool flag>
class A
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class A<T,true>
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    A<int, false> a;
    a.f();

    A<int, true> b;
    b.f();
}
```